# The model's accuracy becomes suddenly so unreasonably good at beginning of the training process. I need an explaination

Tags: long-short-term-memory, sequence-modeling, machine-translation, seq2seq, gated-recurrent-unit

I am practicing machine translation using seq2seq model (more specifically with GRU/LSTM units). The following is my first model:

[image: Model 1 with decoder using one GRU]

This model first archived about 0.03 accuracy score and gradually improved after then. It seems normal.

But when I multiply the decoder's GRU output by 2 (as the following picture)[image],
the model accuracy becomes so good (>0.9)  at the very first epoch of training process (more specifically the first batch). I think it must be wrong somewhere. Can anyone give me an explaination for this?

Comment: After struggling for a few hours, I finally figure out what happened here. Because the appearance of tf.math.multiply layer interrupts the mask propagation. Hence all zero-padded values will be used by the following layers, thus make the accuracy become unreasonable good.